# Github Actions Container is not running

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

The issue happens when entire workflow starts right after Init Containers in Github Actions at actions/checkout@v2.1.0 it spills:

```
Run actions/checkout@v2.1.0
/usr/bin/docker exec  c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894 sh -c "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"
Error response from daemon: Container c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894 is not running
```

Init Containers Log:

```
Checking docker version
Clean up resources from previous jobs
Create local container network
Starting job container
/usr/bin/docker pull rafal1137/etlraspbian
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from rafal1137/etlraspbian
31994f9482cd: Pulling fs layer
76b671f957fb: Pulling fs layer
2782b509b7bd: Pulling fs layer
31994f9482cd: Verifying Checksum
31994f9482cd: Download complete
2782b509b7bd: Verifying Checksum
2782b509b7bd: Download complete
76b671f957fb: Verifying Checksum
76b671f957fb: Download complete
31994f9482cd: Pull complete
76b671f957fb: Pull complete
2782b509b7bd: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c7690eb05c396ab1cda53e2d5a79fa3813f6d2ab673ef42eb3f8d94cbde31ac2
Status: Downloaded newer image for rafal1137/etlraspbian:latest
docker.io/rafal1137/etlraspbian:latest
/usr/bin/docker create --name c2c1009c0f8a45debcf7b67d292ec3fc_rafal1137etlraspbian_5d0ed5 --label 5588e4 --workdir /__w/etlegacy/etlegacy --network github_network_4c8199090d9347ee87e039d67b6a0a4a  -e "HOME=/github/home" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work":"/__w" -v "/home/runner/runners/2.277.1/externals":"/__e":ro -v "/home/runner/work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/home/runner/work/_actions":"/__w/_actions" -v "/opt/hostedtoolcache":"/__t" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" --entrypoint "tail" rafal1137/etlraspbian "-f" "/dev/null"
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894
/usr/bin/docker start c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894
c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894
/usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894 --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894 Up Less than a second
/usr/bin/docker inspect --format "{{range .Config.Env}}{{println .}}{{end}}" c30dd34bb8ac19329d0971b0808f9a4440b20a31283dbfb70b5249619e3dc894
HOME=/github/home
GITHUB_ACTIONS=true
CI=true
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Waiting for all services to be ready
```

[Container Used](https://hub.docker.com/r/rafal1137/etlraspbian)

Tested locally on my pc container seems to work without issues.

Comment: What is your GitHub Actions workflow.yml configuration file?

Comment: @GuiFalourd This change in workflow yml is long gone. But part of this looked like this.
https://pastebin.com/9Z1cvjM3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're building in **linux/arm** and Github is using **linux/amd64**.

> The requested image's platform (linux/arm) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested.

Try building the image under **linux/amd64** with [Docker buildx](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/) or, if you're using Docker compose, with [Platform](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#platform) option, then push it and try again.

Try:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 . -t docker.io/username/repo
```

Comment: This just worked for me. Thanks Arral! For anyone else, the relevant command is `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 . -t docker.io/username/repo`

Comment: super helpful question and answer.  this worked for me as well. it would be great to add that `docker buildx` line to the accepted answer for others @RichPauloo @arall !! many many thanks

Comment: For me `docker build . --platform linux/amd64 -t docker.io/username/repo` also worked.